# How to download several files from multiple website with Scrapy or WGET or other tools

Tags: excel, csv, pdf, scrapy, web-crawler

My aim is to be able to make legal and safe data collection on internet mainly on economic figures.

I want to be able to harvest on specific websites (WTO, OECD, IMF and WHO) excel sheets and pdf that they provide for free and pool them in csv files. 
I started to learn Scrappy and trained myself with wget. But before I try harder to find some way to build something on my own,

I would like to know if it is technically possible or if someone has experience in crawling, harvesting and store in csv files, documents from multiple sources on different websites.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/help for information about how to ask questions here.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but as is this is WAY too broad. We're not going to help you write a crawler from scratch. We're here to help fix code - you write some, we'll (maybe) help get it working.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer I'll try to be more specific and prepare more detailed and shortest question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use HTTrack to download entire websites or parts of them by URL, but it can be configured to download only specific pages and their links to a depth of just 1 and also to download only specific types of files by pattern matching their names to "+*.xls" or whatever works for you.  Addditional its configuration for a run is saved so it can be run again and possibly automated with a scheduler. HTTrack is free opensource and has distros for Windows, Linux, OSX, FreeBSD and Android. For more info see https://www.httrack.com/ and https://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html.

Comment: Thank you Tris, Your help is really appreciated and I 'll combine your suggestion with my firsts tests and share it.